# Activity intent -- Unfortunately has stopped

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to use a button intent Activity to Activity.
This is my program.

this is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ibaby_single_picture.MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text = "123"
    ></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my java(activity):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);        
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}   
private Button.OnClickListener listener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),informationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}; 
}
```

this is my AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ibaby_single_picture.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>    //↓I have written this.
    <activity android:label="iBaby" android:name=".informationActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

I don't know where is the mistake.
Could someone help me?
Thanks a lot!!!!!!!

Is this stacktrace?

```
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: gotoinformationActivity [class android.view.View]
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3835)
09-20 01:21:35.944: E/AndroidRuntime(28696):    ... 11 more
```

This is my informationActivity. I used Tabhost extends Activity.

```
public class informationActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.information_tabhost);

    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = getActionBar().newTab();
    tab1.setText("1");
    tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener1(new information0()));

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = getActionBar().newTab();
    tab2.setText("2");
    tab2.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_edit);
    tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener1(new information1()));

    ActionBar.Tab tab3 = getActionBar().newTab();
    tab3.setText("3");
    tab3.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
    tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener1(new information2()));

    ActionBar.Tab tab4 = getActionBar().newTab();
    tab3.setText("3");
    tab3.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
    tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener1(new information3()));

    getActionBar().addTab(tab1);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab2);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab3);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab4);
}

private class TabListener1 implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment fragment;
    public TabListener1(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        ft.add(R.id.tabsample1, fragment);
    }


    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
}
```

And this is my information_tabhost.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/tabsample1" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Really thanks,everyone!

Comment: is that activity_main.xml?

Comment: Yes,that is activity_main.xml.

Comment: Post your stacktrace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: `NoSuchMethodException: gotoinformationActivity`

Comment: post InformationActivity.class file

Comment: I post it! thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Please change your manifest, add package in manifest file

```
android:label="iBaby"
android:name="com.example.ibaby_single_picture.informationActivity">
```

Comment: Fun Kaaro  Yaarrrrrrrrr

Comment: Please send the crash

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),informationActivity.class);
       StartActivity(intent);

Comment: Please change and change this

Comment: I had already solved it ! There is something wrong in my informationActivity. Thank you!